# Access array elements in a django template - "field not found error" due to unicode referencing

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to access the elements of an array from within a Django template but I am getting a "field * not found" error. My template syntax is as follows:

```
<h3>Data:</h3>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr><th> Row[0] </th><th> Row[1] </th><th> Row[2] </th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for row in info %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
        <td align = 'center'>{{ row.1 }}</td>
        <td align = 'center'>{{ row.2 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Reading through my stack trace it looks like the problem is that the template engine is trying to reference the array fields using unicode versions of the subscripts; so that:

- `{{ row.0 }}` is referenced as `row[u'0']` rather than `row[0]`

thereby causing the error.

The exact error is: `Caught ValueError while rendering: field named 0 not found`

It is occuring at:

```
current = context
    try: # catch-all for silent variable failures
        for bit in self.lookups:
            try: # dictionary lookup
==>             current = current[bit]
            except (TypeError, AttributeError, KeyError):
                try: # attribute lookup
                    current = getattr(current, bit)
                except (TypeError, AttributeError):
                    try: # list-index lookup
                        current = current[int(bit)]
```

So it isn't getting to the point where it tries the list-index lookup. Why would this be?

Comment: If my answer won't help please provide the content of `info` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested forloops instead of explicit item indexing:

```
{% for row in info %}
<tr>
    {% for value in row %}
    <td {% if forloop.counter > 0 %}align = 'center'{% endif %}> {{ value }} </td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

{{ row.0 }} should be work. if no - write templatetag with your own logic for this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get(l, i):
    return l[int(i)]
```